# How to display only 2 lines when a mousemove event occurs on a canvas

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to make two lines that follows the mouse every time the MouseMove event occurs. I can create the two lines for the event, but the problem is that they will create two lines for every MouseMove. Here's my code. I'm using WPF and C#.

```
    private void CanvasMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        double xPos = e.GetPosition(m_Grid).X;
        double yPos = e.GetPosition(m_Grid).Y;

        Line vertLine = new Line();
        Line horzLine = new Line();

        vertLine.X1 = xPos;
        vertLine.Y1 = 0;
        vertLine.X2 = xPos;
        vertLine.Y2 = m_Grid.Height;

        horzLine.X1 = 0;
        horzLine.Y1 = yPos;
        horzLine.X2 = m_Grid.Width;
        horzLine.Y2 = yPos;

        vertLine.StrokeThickness = 1;
        horzLine.StrokeThickness = 1;

        vertLine.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
        horzLine.Stroke = Brushes.Black;

        m_Grid.Children.Add(vertLine); //m_Grid is my Canvas
        m_Grid.Children.Add(horzLine);

        m_Grid.UpdateLayout();
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried moving the existing lines on the canvas as opposed to creating new ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `Clear` the `Grid.Children` every time (also don't call `UpdateLayout`, it's none of your business).

Comment: Thank you!!! You gave me a hint on this. I was stuck on how to clear the 2 lines. :D

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to find the existing lines and then remove them, this way if you have anything else in your canvas you won't be removing it, only these specific lines.

You can do this by giving them a name and then searching for them with that name.

```
private void CanvasMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            double xPos = e.GetPosition(m_Grid).X;
            double yPos = e.GetPosition(m_Grid).Y;

            Line vertLine = new Line
                                {
                                    Name = "vertLine",
                                    X1 = xPos,
                                    Y1 = 0,
                                    X2 = xPos,
                                    Y2 = m_Grid.Height,
                                    Stroke = Brushes.Black,
                                    StrokeThickness = 1
                                };

            Line horzLine = new Line
                                {
                                    Name = "horzLine",
                                    X1 = 0,
                                    Y1 = yPos,
                                    X2 = m_Grid.Width,
                                    Y2 = yPos,
                                    StrokeThickness = 1,
                                    Stroke = Brushes.Black
                                };

            m_Grid.Children.Remove((Line) m_Grid.Children.OfType<Line>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "vertLine"));
            m_Grid.Children.Remove((Line) m_Grid.Children.OfType<Line>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "horzLine"));

            m_Grid.Children.Add(vertLine); //m_Grid is my Canvas
            m_Grid.Children.Add(horzLine);

            m_Grid.UpdateLayout();
        }
```